# Are you guys ready for a QUESTion?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Chase me and my feet are not slow

Catch me then skywards I go

What am I?

Hints:

> There could be three people speaking here.

> The two clues hint at two words to make one.

> A V with rock, an L with bridge and an M with a bow

> A Quest to stop a plague, will you oblidge? (Not Covid 19)

Last hint:

> Peaked in 2007

Comment: This is my original puzzle

Comment: Are you someone who's [messing with giants in Skyrim?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWV9hSDXTkg)

Comment: Lol that was funny...

Comment: May I ask: rot(13) Ner gur nafjre guerr pbzvpf/zbivr punenpgref?

Comment: It's been a while. Can you give us some more clues??

Answer (score 1):

I think you are,

> Ion Thruster or Ion propulsion device

Reasons:

> Quest - "ion". Ion was a clue
>  Ion propulsion engines are used in spacecrafts (Skywards)

Comment: Not the answer sorry

Comment: Hmm... I need to think deeply, it seems 

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Are you

> The Snitch from Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire?

Chase me and my feet are not slow

> In the book/film, the goal of the game is to catch The Snitch but it moves very fast.

Catch me then skywards I go

> If the Snitch is caught, then you go skywards to victory.

Title:

> Quest for the Snitch ;)

Hint #1:

> The 3 people are Harry, Hermione, and Ron.

Hint #2:

> The and Snitch are 2 words.

Hint #3:

> Wings are v shaped, made of gold which is a rock, flies over bridges during the game, bow symbolises the arch in Hogwarts school.

Cannot understand the last hint, but I'll guess that sales of the Harry Potter series peaked in 2007.

Note: OP has clarified that this answer is wrong, but I will leave this answer here for inspiration for future answers. In the meantime, I will try to solve the puzzle myself.

Comment: Two words too make one word...

Comment: Is it correct? I don't understand

Comment: No you need to make one word look at the tag

Comment: Explain "Peaked 2007"

Comment: I did this answer before the last hint, but I will make it a partial answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

> [Financial crisis of 2007-2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%932008)

Explanation

> "V with rock": the Northern Rock bank received support from the Bank of England, V may refer to the boom of panic and bank run

> "L with bridge": the failure of the bridge bank, IndyMac Federal Bank

> "M with a bow": may refer to the whistleblower Richard M. Bowen III

Comment: Wrong answer...